# BroadcastReceiver for Ethernet(RJ45) and USB in Android TV

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-tv, television, receiver

How can i detect the plug and unplug of **Ethernet cable** and **USB** devices(Any device like pendrive) in Android TV. Is there any receiver for that as like internet connectivity?

I need to check for by TVBox app.

**Solution:**

Got Solution for ETHERNET - 
can be checked by **TYPE_ETHERNET** in **ConnectivityManager**

but Still USB remaining

Comment: this site is not appropriate for your question

Comment: then which site? i think this is developer forum only

Comment: @DavidHackro, the question seems perfectly fine. Would you mind to elaborate on why the downwote?

Answer (score 1):

#### Ethernet

Check out [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) for the the connection type [TYPE_ETHERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_ETHERNET)

#### USB

Check out [UsbManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html) for the broadcast [ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED).